# OLED with arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno, serial

I recently bought a 0.96" Serial OLED Screen. I am not very experienced with this. I'm trying to display some text with the Arduino Uno. I installed the adafruit SSD1306 and GFX libraries but no luck. I've looked for tutorials for similar screens, but my screen has extra pins that others don't.

Mine has:
`CS` `DC` `RST` `D1` `D0` `VCC` `GND`,
others only have 4.

I don't know what each pin should be connected to. Does any one know how to get this to work? Is there a different library that I could use with this screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, certain OLED screens do have different pinouts. For yours, the following would be your OLED's pinouts.

```
OLED ---- Arduino

D0-----------10

D1-----------9

RST----------13

DC-----------11

VCC----------5V

GND----------GND
```

The `CS` pin does not need to be plugged in.

As for the code, you can use [this include](http://smart-prototyping.com/image/data/2_components/Arduino/100952%20OLED%200.96inch%2012864%20display%20module%20blue/OELD.txt) from Smart Prototyping as an extra file, then have some simple code in your `loop` portion:

```
void loop()
{

LED_P8x16Str(23,0,"here is");

LED_P8x16Str(40,2,"example");

LED_P8x16Str(20,4,"text");

}
```

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help!